# Why is non-exist javascript file being executed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

My folder architecture is:

Script--->App--->Administration--->UserModel.js

I use knockoutjs so I bound my html to javascript like this:

**AddUser.cshtml**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        require(["Administration/UserModel"], function (userModel) {
            var userModel = new userModel();
            ko.applyBindings(userModel, document.getElementById("AddUserForm"));
        });
    });
</script>
```

**UserModel.js**

```
 return function () {
        var self = this;
        self.email = ko.observable("");
        self.password = ko.observable("");

        self.createUser = function () {
            webRequest.postJSON("/Administration/User/CreateUser", ko.toJSON(self), self.saveSucceeded);
        }
}
```

I deleted my UserModel.js file and started the project then I checked from firebug and I noticed that It posted observables. This file is still being executed. However I deleted this file. Where did it come from?

Comment: Did you clear the browser cache?

Comment: Also please check if you have really deleted file itself (not only excluded it from the VS project)

Comment: I hadn't considered that. Thanks..

Comment: To clear cache is the solution.